# How to get the solution to these differential equations

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to get from

$$
\tan(x) = \frac{y''}{y'} + y'
$$

The answer is

$$
y = \ln(c_1\tanh^{-1}(\tan(\frac{x}{2}))+c_2)
$$

The other equation is

$$
\sec(x) = \frac{y''}{y'}+y'
$$

The answer is

$$
y = \ln(c_1\ln(e^{4\tanh^{-1}(\tan(\frac{x}{2}))}+1)+c_2)
$$

I have no idea where to begin, Any advice would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we write $$y(x) := \log u(x),$$ then the first equation (after some work) reduces to
$$\frac{y''}{y'} + y' = \frac{u''}{u'} = (\log (u'))'.$$ So, integrating both sides of, e.g., the first equation, which we now write as
$$\tan x = (\log (u'))'$$
gives
$$\log \sec x = \log (u') + C,$$
or
$$u' = C_1 \sec x.$$
Integrating again gives
$$u = C_1 \log(\sec x + \tan x) + C_2,$$
which immediately gives solutions $y$.

Comment: The Chain Rule gives that $y' = \frac{u'}{u}$ and $y'' = \frac{u''}{u} - \frac{(u')^2}{u^2}$; then, substitute and simplify.

Comment: Both of them work interestingly enough, but i don't understand how...

Comment: What don't you understand exactly?

Comment: Nothing, just thought about it. Ofcourse ode can have 2 different solutions.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean. Note that $\text{artanh } s = \frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{1 + s}{1 - s}\right)$, and evaluate the right-hand side at $s = tan t$ and simplify the expression in parentheses using a trigonometric identity. This shows that this solution is just the one you mentioned in the question in disguise.

Answer (score 2):

dividing by $y^\prime$ turns $ {y^{\prime \prime} \over y^{\prime}} + y^{\prime} = f(x)$  into $ {y^{\prime \prime} \over {y^{\prime}}^2} + 1 = \frac{f}{y^{\prime}}$ which is 
$$-\frac{d(1/y^{\prime})}{dx} + 1 =\frac{f}{y^\prime}$$ make a change of variable $u =  1/y^\prime$ so that $${du \over dx} = 1 - uf$$ we will try variation of parameters, i.e. $$ u = Ae^{-\int_0^x f(t)dt} \mbox{where $A$ is a function of $x$ to be determined.}$$ substituting this in the equation for $u$ gives 
$$ e^{-\int_0^x f(t)dt } \frac{dA}{dx }- e^{-\int_0^x f(t)dt }Af = 1 - Ae^{-\int_0^x f(t)dt }f$$ so that $$ A = \int_0^x e^{-\int_0^x f(t)dt }dx + C, u = e^{-\int_0^x f(t)dt }\left( \int_0^x e^{-\int_0^x f(t)dt }dx + C \right)$$

one can now substitute $ \tan x \mbox{ and } \sec x$  for $f.$

Answer (score 0):

let $y=ln(z)$

then $y'=\frac1z z'$

and $y''=\frac{-1}{z^2}(z')^2+\frac1z z''$

so $\frac {y''}{y'}=\frac{-1}z z' +\frac{z''}{z'}$

sub all in to ODE you end up with $\tan(x) = \frac{z''}{z'}$

now let $Q=\frac1{z'}$

then $Q'=\frac{-1}{(z')^2}z''=\frac{-1}{z'} \frac{z''}{z'}=-Q\frac{z''}{z'}$

so $\frac{z''}{z'}=\frac{-Q'}{Q}$

so our ODE now becomes $\tan(x)=\frac{-Q'}{Q}$

which is simply $\frac1Q dQ=- \tan(x)dx$

so $ln(Q)=-ln(\sec(x))+c=ln( \cos(x))+c$

so $Q=e^{ln(\cos(x))+c}=A \cos(x)$

sub this in to $Q=A \cos(x)=\frac1{z'}$

which is same as $dz=C_1 \sec(x)dx$

so $z=C_1(ln(\sec(x)+ \tan(x)))+C_2$

ao $y=ln (C_1(ln(\sec(x)+ \tan(x)))+C_2)$

perhaps if we pick different substitution we get the answer that you have but i don't know how and this method works for second ODE too

we start this here $\frac1Q dQ=- \sec(x)dx$

Then $ln(Q)=ln(\sec(x)+\tan(x))+c$

which is same as $Q=A(\sec(x)+\tan(x))$

so $Q=\frac1{z'}=A(\sec(x)+\tan(x))$

so $dz=C_1 \frac{ \cos(x)}{1+\sin(x)} dx$

which is $z=ln(C_1(ln(1+\sin(x)))+c_2$

so $y=ln(ln(C_1(ln(1+\sin(x)))+c_2)$